# What is the best use-case of Appium Server Start and Stop. Is the Appium Server Start and Stop @BeforeTest and @AfterTest

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, appium, appium-android

What is the best practice for using the Appium Server Start and Stop on every test class start and Stop or anything else??

I am adding AppiumServer.start(); and AppiumServer.stop(); on every test class @Before and @After Test. When I run all the test class through the testng.xml after running 2/3 classes I get the socket hang up error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best to start appium server for a session , you run all your tests and then close appium session. If you are using pytest then use session scope pytest fixture. Use `yield` after starting server and once tests are finished running, then stops server.

Comment: I am using Java and TestNG

Comment: Try ```@BeforeSuite``` and ```@AfterSuite```, which runs before and after all runs in a test suite.